# I get different answers for the same trigonometric equation!

Tags: trigonometry

Hello exercise is to solve this equation:

$$2 \sin (3x + 2 \pi) + \sqrt {2} = 0$$

I get 3 different sets of answers


**1.Equation Solved By me:**
[image]

**2. Equation solved by website with answers**

[image]

**3. And by the calculator**
[image]

As you can see none of those answers are the same as the others, so which one is correct then?

Comment: Are these not the same? They seem to be off by multiples of $\tfrac{2\pi}3$, which is captured in the latter term.

Comment: To add to the previous comment: write a few of those solutions down, for,  say, $n=-5,-4,-3, -2,-1, 0, 1,2,3, 4,  5$ and compare what you get. (You will inevitably get the same answers, but they may not be generated from the same $n$ across those three solutions.)

Comment: Ok thanks guys now i get it.

Comment: $2\sin(3x+6\pi)+\sqrt2=0\iff2\sin(3x)+\sqrt2$. It follows $\sin(3x)=-\sin(\frac{\pi}{4})$ so $3x=(2n-\frac14)\pi$ and $3x=(2n+\frac54)\pi$. Consequently the solution is given by the double set 
$$x=\frac{(8n-1)\pi}{12}; n\in\mathbb Z\\x=\frac{(8n+5)\pi}{12}; n\in\mathbb Z$$

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to show the answers of a trigonometric equation, but Piquito's version is usually the best practice, i.e. keeping everything simple.

As your solutions are in the third and fourth quadrants, the solutions will be negative.  The principal answers in the range of $0$ to $2 \pi$ are $$x = \frac {5 \pi}{12}, \frac {7 \pi}{12}$$ but the general answers for any angle coterminal to those are $$x = \frac {5 \pi}{12}+\frac {2 \pi k}{3}, \frac {7 \pi}{12}+\frac {2 \pi k}{3}$$

One convention is to keep the answers positive when putting them under a common denominator, so we have $$x = \frac {\pi(8k + 5)}{12}, \frac {\pi(8k + 7)}{12}$$ in the counterclockwise direction, going from the first quadrant to the fourth.  However, in the clockwise direction (the fourth quadrant to the first) we get $$x = \frac {\pi(8k - 1)}{12}, \frac {\pi(8k - 3)}{12}$$ thus so long as the solutions return the principal values, we can use positive only, negative only, or a mix of the two.

For the answers that the website and the calculator gave, the angle $-\frac {19 \pi}{12}$ (and $-\frac {11 \pi}{12}$) is coterminal with $\frac {7 \pi}{12}$ and $-\frac {17 \pi}{12}$ is coterminal with $\frac {5 \pi}{12}$.  Those answers are also correct for $k \lt 0$.